# Python: I fell in an infinite loop

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop

The problem states as follows:

```
Example output:

Calculator
Give the first number: 100
Give the second number: 25
(1) +
(2) -
(3) *
(4) /
(5)Change numbers
(6)Quit
Current numbers: 100 25
Please select something (1-6): 5
Give the first number: 10
Give the second number: 30
(1) +
(2) -
(3) *
(4) /
(5)Change numbers
(6)Quit
Current numbers: 10 30
Please select something (1-6): 1
The result is: 40
(1) +
(2) -
(3) *
(4) /
(5)Change numbers
(6)Quit
Current numbers: 10 30
Please select something (1-6): 6
Thank you!
```

And my solution was:

```
print("Calculator")

var1 = input("Give the first number: ")
var2 = input("Give the second number: ")

print("(1) +\n(2) -\n(3) *\n(4) /\n(5)Change numbers\n(6)Quit")
print("Current numbers: " + var1 + " " + var2)

opcion = input("Please select something (1-6): ")

while (opcion != "6"):
    if (opcion == "1"):
        var3 = int(var1) + int(var2)
        print("The result is: " + str(var3))
    elif (opcion == "2"):
        var3 = int(var1) - int(var2)
        print("The result is: " + str(var3))
    elif (opcion == "3"):
        var3 = int(var1) * int(var2)
        print("The result is: " + str(var3))
    elif (opcion == "4"):
        var3 = int(var1) / int(var2)
        print("The result is: " + str(var3))
    elif (opcion == "5"):
        var1 = input("Give the first number: ")
        var2 = input("Give the second number: ")
        opcion = input("Please select something (1-6): ")
    else:
        print("Selection was not correct.")

print("Thank you!")
```

But in "elif (opcion == "5"):" the automatic corrector states that I fell in an infinite loop, I tried a break after the two new numbers are entered, but it completely exits from the while-loop, any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: You set `opcion` *once* before the loop, and then you loop without ever changing the value of `opcion`. So, yes, unless `opcion` is `6` the very first time around, it won't ever change and the loop will never terminate...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem in your code:**

You only assign `opcion` outside the `while` loop and after which you are only modifying `opcion` when `opcion == "5"`.

What happens when you give `opcion = "1"` is it adds and gives you the answer and after which checks the while statement when is true, because `opcion` did not change. It then adds again, and checks again, and `goes oooooooooooon`, so an infinite loop is produced.

**Modification:**

```
print("Calculator")

var1 = input("Give the first number: ")
var2 = input("Give the second number: ")

print("(1) +\n(2) -\n(3) *\n(4) /\n(5)Change numbers\n(6)Quit")
print("Current numbers: " + var1 + " " + var2)

while True:
    opcion = input("Please select something (1-6): ")
    if (opcion == "1"):
        var3 = int(var1) + int(var2)
        print("The result is: " + str(var3))
    elif (opcion == "2"):
        var3 = int(var1) - int(var2)
        print("The result is: " + str(var3))
    elif (opcion == "3"):
        var3 = int(var1) * int(var2)
        print("The result is: " + str(var3))
    elif (opcion == "4"):
        var3 = int(var1) / int(var2)
        print("The result is: " + str(var3))
    elif (opcion == "5"):
        var1 = input("Give the first number: ")
        var2 = input("Give the second number: ")
    elif (opcion == "6"):
        break
    else:
        print("Selection was not correct.")

print("Thank you!")
```

**More improved solution:**

```
import operator
print("Calculator")

var1 = input("Give the first number: ")
var2 = input("Give the second number: ")

print("(1) +\n(2) -\n(3) *\n(4) /\n(5)Change numbers\n(6)Quit")
print("Current numbers: " + var1 + " " + var2)
operations={"1":operator.add,"2":operator.sub,"3":operator.mul,"4":operator.div}
while True:
    option = input("Please select something (1-6): ")
    print option
    if option in operations:
        var3=operations[option](int(var1),int(var2))        
        print "value"+str( var3)
        continue
    if (option == "6"):
        print "quiting"
        break
    elif (option == "5"):
        var1 = input("Give the first number: ")
        var2 = input("Give the second number: ")
    else:
        print("Selection was not correct.")

print("Thank you!")
```

**Note :**

It should be `options` and not `opcion` in correct English terms but it really doesn't matter  :P

Comment: Thank you all for you help!

Comment: @LazloZatopek happy to help